# Can I run Ubuntu 14 next to Mac OS X?

Tags: mac

I would love to have Ubuntu but I would also like to keep my Mac. Is there anyway I can just put Ubuntu on a USB stick and then whenever I want to use Ubuntu just plug in the USB and use it.